# Calling .FindByType makes VB6 error out, help?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965767/function-or-interface-marked-as-restricted-or-the-function-uses-an-automation-ty)

Basically, im just searchign for uPnP devices using the uPNPDeviceFinder classes .FindByType method, .FindByUDN works, but FindByType gives an error:

VB6 gives a compile error when I attempt to call the method:

```
Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function
uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic.
```

i have no idea what this even means or why i am getting it. I am referencing and using the upnp.dll file as found in yoru system32 directory - when i reference and use this in VS2010 (say, vb.net) it all works and no issues are found, but in VB6, i get the error above, any ideas anyone? thanks.

Comment: Don't create a new question to enter more information, edit your first question.

Comment: This q is specific to findbytype and the other question is general and about the vb error in general and what it means, they are two different questions, thank you.

Comment: @ho1, dont be going around trying to get my posts deleted, i need coverage due to the obscurity of the question. + reasons given in my last comment.

Comment: No, they are the same question worded slightly differently, as can be seen from the fact that pretty much the same answer was correct for both.

Comment: But anyway, me trying to close this question just makes it link back to the first one, and it can't be deleted for at least 2 days, so you probably didn't loose any exposure. But be careful, too many duplicated questions might annoy some people that might otherwise have answered them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is declared in the typelib as

```
HRESULT FindByType(
                    [in] BSTR bstrTypeURI, 
                    [in] unsigned long dwFlags, 
                    [out, retval] IUPnPDevices** pDevices);
```

and the unsigned parameter `dwFlags` is unusable in VB6

```
Function FindByType(bstrTypeURI As String, dwFlags As <Unsupported variant type>) As UPnPDevices
```

You have to "VB-fy" this typelib by changing param types to compatible VB6 types.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/vbupnp.zip) is my attempt to VB-fy this typelib, use at your own risk. IDL compiled with `mktyplib`.

Note that you don't have to ship `vbupnp.tlb` to your users, you don't have to register it on their machines. Just register and use it on your dev machine only.

Comment: Hi, how do I do this or what can I do on the vb end to get this to work since I can't edit the dll? Thanks

Comment: Remove reference to `upnp.dll` and use `vbupnp.tlb` instead. If you prefixed class names with `UPNPLib` change that to `VBUPNPLib`.

Comment: thanks mate, you are a ledgend, i was trying to get it working but midl was spitting out c precompiler warnings and couldn't convert from idl to tlb, thank you. upvoted and accepted as answer.

Comment: btw, do you recomment mktyplib over midl or?

Comment: Both are usable, but `midl` tends to autogenerate stuff -- enum names, etc. -- so `mktyplib` is leaner and specificly targeted at typelibs and included in VB6 distro so its kind of "official" tool in VB6. `midl`'s main purpose is to generate interface proxies/stubs, typelibs kind of feel like byproduct.

Comment: thanks wqw, how do i learn about what proxies and stubs are and how to make use of these? i had never heard of .idl files and methods of tricking intellisense into using altered .tlb files.